# Problems with Biblatex and bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

After I compile my .tex file I get this error:

> LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references. Package biblatex
>   Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s): (biblatex) anteproyecto
>   (biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

This is the structure of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paper,
  author =       "You and Me",
  title =        "Hello",
  note =         "World",
  year =         "2013",
  keywords =     "mobile"
}
@online{icao,
    title     = "We all",
    url       = "http://www.latex.com",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\begin{document}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I use Texmaker editor (I configured for UTF8 enconding and biblatex + pdflatex compiling) and Texlive.
I am newbie with tex. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! That cannot possibly be the warning message produced when compiling the code you posted. Please ensure that you copy-paste errors and warnings and that they are actually produced by the code you post.

Comment: @cfr thanks for your answer. It can possibly be the warning produced when compiling the code I posted. I copied the error from the log. It is correct.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make any use of Biblatex whatsoever. Moreover, you cannot use `biblatex + pdflatex` for compiling because `biblatex` is not a binary. There is no such programme. Whatever you are seeing, the warning you posted, is not from that code.

Comment: And by the way, the `filecontents` environment should come *before* `\documentclass`. If you want to use the package, put `\RequirePackage{filecontents}` first, but remember this will overwrite existing files.

Comment: @cfr OK. I will tell you what you want to hear: that error is not from that code. Feel happy? And thanks for the hints.

Comment: Really, I'd like to know where it is coming from. Unsolved puzzles are intriguing.

Comment: Apparently [the source of the error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270822/problems-with-biblatex-and-bibtex#comment651469_270827) is, indeed, code which differs from that given in the question in just the way one would expect i.e. that code loads Biblatex which is 'forgotten' here.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you do not cite any document.  Also you tagged `biblatex` but you didn't load the package in the given code.

I added `\nocite{*}` to create a bibliography of all bib entrys in your bib file.

See this MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{paper,
  author =       "You and Me",
  title =        "Hello",
  note =         "World",
  year =         "2013",
  keywords =     "mobile",
}
@online{icao,
    title     = "We all",
    url       = "http://www.latex.com",
    keywords  = "latex",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} %  bib file created with filecontents

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}          % shows allbib entrys in bibliography
\printbibliography  % print bibliography here
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Please see that you have to use `biber` in this version!

Comment: I forgot the package `biblatex`, it was loaded. Anyway, it still does not work. I really do not understand. This is the new output in the error log: `This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: anteproyecto.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file anteproyecto.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file anteproyecto.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file anteproyecto.aux (There were 3 error messages) Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: @verovan I'm a bit late to the party, but I would still like to point out that you need to run Biber and not BibTeX as Kurt points out. See [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and finally, [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). (You could make the document accept BibTeX by changing using `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`, but that will have other drawbacks.)

Comment: I don't have TeX Live, so I can't test with that. The thing with `\addbibresource` not working if `.bib` is not included is something I picked up in a forum, so I'm not too sure about it and I can't remember the details.